# SAP UI5 Live Search in Input Box not working

Tags: odata, sapui5

I followed this example, https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputAssisted to develop a functionality similar to this, but my input box is not populating and not searching as I write. When I press help dialog button, all values are listed, but I cannot search within them.

Code is below:
View.xml:

```
<Input
    id="productInput"
    type="Text"
    placeholder="Enter Product ..."
    showSuggestion="true"
    valueHelpRequest="handleValueHelp"
    showValueHelp="true"
    suggestionItems="{AgrName}" >
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item text="{AgrName}" />
    </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

Converting Odata to JSON in Controller init function

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGETJOBROLES_SRV/", true);

oModel.setSizeLimit(100000);
this.getView().setModel(oModel);

var jsonModel = "";
oModel.read("/DefineRolesTableSet", null, null, false, function(oData, oResponse) {
    jsonModel = oData;

});

var jData = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(jsonModel);

this.getView().setModel(jData, "dataModel");
console.log(jData);
```

handleValueHelp function

```
handleValueHelp: function(oEvent) {

    var sInputValue = oEvent.getSource().getValue();

    this.inputId = oEvent.getSource().getId();
    //sInputValue.getModel().getJSON(); 
    // create value help dialog
    if (!this._valueHelpDialog) {
        this._valueHelpDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
            "JobRoleSearch.View.Dialog",
            this
        );
        this.getView().addDependent(this._valueHelpDialog);
    }

    // create a filter for the binding

    this._valueHelpDialog.getBinding("items").filter([new Filter(
        "AgrName",
        sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sInputValue
    )]);

    // open value help dialog filtered by the input value
    this._valueHelpDialog.open(sInputValue);
}
```

[Results of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKNH2.png)

My intention is to search on client end, not on server side, which is why I have converted oData to JSON. 
If there is any mistake, please let me know.

Regards

Comment: TRY suggestionItems="{dataModel >/results}"

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to SAPUI5 there are some OpenSAP courses for free, where you can watch some tutorials and practive [enter link description here](https://open.sap.com/courses/ui52), I guess there is a problem with your model, try `suggestionItems="{/AgrName}"`.
Here is an example of binding a local json model:

1. Manifest.json

   ```
   "mainService": {
           "uri": "",
           "type": "OData",
           "settings": {
               "odataVersion": "2.0",
               "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
           }
       },
       "resource": {
           "type": "JSON",
           "uri": "model/Resources.json"
       },
       "location": {
           "type": "JSON",
           "uri": "model/Locations.json"
       }
   ```
2. Json file:

   {"Resource":[{
   "ID":1, 
   "Name": "TitMLocations", 
   "Number": 0, 
   "ValueColor":"Good", 
   "Icon": "sap-icon://building", 
   "LocationType":""
   }, {
   "ID": 2, 
   "Name": "TitMCar", 
   "Number": 0, 
   "ValueColor":"Good", 
   "Icon": "sap-icon://car-rental"
   }, {
   "ID": 3, 
   "Name": "TitMEquipment", 
   "Number": 0, 
   "ValueColor":"Good", 
   "Icon": "sap-icon://add-equipment"
   }]
   }
3. XML Binding

   items="{resource>/Resource}

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. Your suggestion didnt work. I have added results of console.log in the question, please check.

Comment: AgrName is a property, so binding that for suggestionItems won't work. You have to bind the model something like suggestionItems="{dataModel>/}".

Comment: No, it doesnt work. Tried dataModel>/ , dataModel>/results , dataModel>/oData, dataModel>/oData/results ...None of them work.